# Geometric explanation of a contour's image

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, parametric, curves

$$\gamma(t)= t^2 + i\, t^4 , \quad t\in [ -1, 1]$$

What is the geometric explanation of the image of the above contour? Intuitively , I think it's ellipsoid-like, but I don't know how to put it in a formal way.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x=t^2$ and $y=t^4 = (t^2)^2 = x^2$.

Comment: It also seems worth emphasizing that $x=t^2\geq 0$.

Comment: So it should be parabolic ?

Comment: @helplessKirk What Semiclassical means is that you don't get a full parabole, but half of it. Only the part where $x \geq 0$. The right portion, using standard axis.

Comment: trying to plot this in wolfram alpha I get a contour plot that looks like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2B+y%5E4%2C+x%3Dy%2C+x%3D-1..1

Comment: @helplessKirk You're not plotting it correctly. I don't know how to describe it to Wolfram, but you are not doing it right. Note that $\gamma(t)$ is a curve in the complex plane, and a very particular one: you can write it as the graph of a function. I told you how, by telling you what is the relation between $y$ and $x$, together with the restriction in $x$. Look at it closely.

Comment: I see the relation between the two. If I wrote it as $\gamma(x)=x+ix^2 ,  x\in[0,1]$ ,would it be the proper way? Thank you for time, I appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: In a 3 dimensional space, $\gamma(t)$ is the right portion of a parabole , which is closer to the Imaginary plane and its image ranges from 0 to 1+i ?

Comment: @helplessKirk I wouldn't use "proper way". Writing it as you did should make the curve more explicit. Be careful: $\gamma(t)$ is **not** in a $3$ dimensional space. You are correct that $\gamma(t)$ is the right portion of a parabole, but that's a planar figure. You can't speak of a "right portion" in $3D$. And yes, the end points of the curve are $0$ and $1+i$.